# Simple code error for beginner - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, find, runtime-error

My problem is:

- I have 2 columns on sheet "Crono" that display an event and where it took place. I need to add two more columns with the start date and the end date of the event

The information is all on another sheet ("Projetos Novo").
The number of events is variable and that's why I created the variable i.

When I run the code it appears `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set`

it actually copies the first six dates and then crashes.

I so need your kind help!!

```
Sub Datas()

Dim w As Long
Dim t As Long
Dim i As Long


t = Sheets("Crono").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


For i = 8 To t

w = Sheets("Projetos NOVO").Range("C:C").Find(Sheets("Crono").Range("A" & i).Value).Row


If Sheets("Projetos NOVO").Range("D" & w).Find(Sheets("Crono").Range("C" & i).Value).Row Then


Sheets("Crono").Range("F" & i).Value = Sheets("Projetos NOVO").Range("R" & w).Value
Sheets("Crono").Range("G" & i).Value = Sheets("Projetos NOVO").Range("S" & w).Value

Else

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You should be working with a `Range` variable, and then testing if the value from *Crono* is found (if it isn't found you will get the error you currently see);

```
Sub Datas()

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim t As Long
Dim i As Long

t = Sheets("Crono").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 8 To t

Set rng1 = Sheets("Projetos NOVO").Range("C:C").Find(Sheets("Crono").Range("A" & i).Value)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox rng1.Row
Else
    MsgBox Sheets("Crono").Range("A" & i).Value & " not found"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

the problem is, then i want to go to the other sheet and copy two values from two cells (column R and S) and the row number is the w I as using above. My error is on the if I guess :\

Comment: I don't if I am making it clear enough.
I am sorry for my english!

but i want this w to be the row number where it is found the value to use it later with the if